# Connection refused [tcp://redis:6380] - Laradock

Tags: laravel, redis, laradock

Into my Laravel project I get this error message:

```
Predis\Connection\ConnectionException
Connection refused [tcp://redis:6380]
```

Settings Laravel .env

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6380
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```

I added this to config/database.php

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
        'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
    ],

    'default' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'redis'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6380),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'redis'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6380),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
    ],

],
```

Into laradock .env I changed the redis port

```
### REDIS #################################################
REDIS_PORT=6380

...
REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_HOST=redis
REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_PORT=6379
REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_DB=0
REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_PASSWORD=None
REDIS_RESULT_STORAGE_SERVER_HOST=redis
REDIS_RESULT_STORAGE_SERVER_PORT=6379
REDIS_RESULT_STORAGE_SERVER_DB=0
REDIS_RESULT_STORAGE_SERVER_PASSWORD=None
...

REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_HOST=redis
REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_PORT=6379
REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_DB="0"
REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_PASSWORD=None
...

### REDISWEBUI #########################################
REDIS_WEBUI_USERNAME=laradock
REDIS_WEBUI_PASSWORD=laradock
REDIS_WEBUI_CONNECT_HOST=redis
REDIS_WEBUI_CONNECT_PORT=6379
REDIS_WEBUI_PORT=9987
...

WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true
...
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true
```

I stopped all containers and let run:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace
```

Then I opend my laravel website and get this error.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change port to 6379 in laravel and laradock .env:

```
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

> And restart server

Comment: I can't because there is another redis server at this port

Comment: very interesting:)